# Detect when form submission is complete

Tags: javascript, forms, amazon-s3

I have a form that posts directly to an AWS S3 bucket using an [AWS S3 Presigned POST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-post.html) so I have no control over what is done server-side after the form submission.

How do I detect when the form submission/uploading process is complete?

Here's how I'm generating the form:

```
    <form<?php foreach ($data['upload_link']['formAttributes'] as $key => $value) {
        echo " $key=\"$value\"";
    } ?>>
        <?php foreach ($data['upload_link']['formInputs'] as $key => $value) {
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$value\">";
        } ?>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    </form>
    <button type="submit" onclick="submitFile()">Upload</button>
```

And here is the javascript that I'm using with it:

```
    function submitFile() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
        document.getElementById('file').value = '';
        updateUploads();
    }
```

I'd like to hold off on performing the updateUploads() function until the upload is complete. Right now, it is updating too soon so the latest upload doesn't populate with the list.

I've attempted to submit with this instead which yields a *412 (Precondition Failed)*:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.data,
            success: function (data) {
                // stuff
            },
            contentType: false
        });
```

Setting contentType to 'multipart/form-data' *yields 400 (Bad Request)* and using a FormData object gives me *Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation*

Comment: sounds like you are looking at doing javascript promise-style calls, is this right?

Comment: If you submit the form, the code after it is not going to run. It replaces the page content. You should be handlling this on the PHP side.

Comment: @epascarello
The code after it does run. It just runs too soon. I literally cannot handle it on the PHP side, since the form submits directly to AWS.

Comment: The issue is the fact that you can not handle it is JavaScript since when you submit it will refresh the page since you are going to AWS.

Comment: You need to use AJAX to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @Mikey
When I tried ajax, I kept getting 400 and 412 errors